# How to change css style for longer time using javascript 'addEventlistner('click')' function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want My css style will change after clicking of a submit button but it will not changing. When i Click button only at that point of time the effect is seen after clicking effect is gone the whole css again change i want that my css style will remain there even after clicking effect gone

```
const btn = document.getElementById("clickbtn");
let value = false;

function addClass() {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.getElementById("registered").style.display = "block";
    });
}

function main() {
    addClass();
}

main();
```

Comment: may be your page get reloaded after submitting, check that

Answer (score 2):

well, I guess you want to have a button and `onclick` event the styling of button should change so I've modified your code a bit. And i hope it will work for you.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("clickbtn");
let value = false;
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
btn.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button id="clickbtn">
Button
</button>
```

let me know, if you need any help. Thanks